# SQL - merge two queries with different number of columns in select statement into one

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are two SQL queries that work as expected when run individually. I've tried clubbing them into one SQL with `UNION` & `UNION ALL` but obviously due to the different number of columns returned by each of these, I'm not able to use these techniques.

The data I'm using is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/byijdz27td05ys0/SALES_INFO.csv?dl=0)

Here are the two separate queries I'm trying to merge

**QUERY ONE**

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 100485760;           
SELECT
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(NUM_PRODS ORDER BY NUM_PRODS SEPARATOR ','),',', 50/100 * COUNT(*) + 1),',', -1) AS DECIMAL) AS aa
    ,CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(NUM_PRODS ORDER BY NUM_PRODS SEPARATOR ','),',', 75/100 * COUNT(*) + 1),',', -1) AS DECIMAL) AS bb
    ,CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(NUM_PRODS ORDER BY NUM_PRODS SEPARATOR ','),',', 85/100 * COUNT(*) + 1),',', -1) AS DECIMAL) AS cc
    ,CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(NUM_PRODS ORDER BY NUM_PRODS SEPARATOR ','),',', 95/100 * COUNT(*) + 1),',', -1) AS DECIMAL) AS dd
    ,MAX(NUM_PRODS) AS MAAX 
FROM 
    SALES_INFO
```

**QUERY TWO**

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 100485760;   
SELECT
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(NUM_PRODS ORDER BY NUM_PRODS SEPARATOR ','),',', 75/100 * COUNT(*) + 1),',', -1) AS DECIMAL) AS ee
FROM 
    SALES_INFO
WHERE
        SALE_DATE >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

Could I please request help to merge these two queries into one?

Comment: You need to identify columns that are unique to each record sets. In the union part, specify null or default values for the columns that available in each table or record set into a common table expression. You can now query the CTE like you like. You can read about <a href="https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx"> CTE</a> if you do not know about it. A very useful tool in SQL server. You can adapt equivalent of it to mysql as well.

Comment: And not so useful elsewhere

Comment: You can add NULLs as placeholders

Comment: Merge how? Show us the two (resonably small) original results, and the expected combined result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery in the select, like this:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(NUM_PRODS ORDER BY NUM_PRODS SEPARATOR ','),',', 50/100 * COUNT(*) + 1),',', -1) AS DECIMAL) AS 50per
       ,CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(NUM_PRODS ORDER BY NUM_PRODS SEPARATOR ','),',', 75/100 * COUNT(*) + 1),',', -1) AS DECIMAL) AS 75per
       ,CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(NUM_PRODS ORDER BY NUM_PRODS SEPARATOR ','),',', 85/100 * COUNT(*) + 1),',', -1) AS DECIMAL) AS 85per
       ,CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(NUM_PRODS ORDER BY NUM_PRODS SEPARATOR ','),',', 95/100 * COUNT(*) + 1),',', -1) AS DECIMAL) AS 95per    
       ,MAX(NUM_PRODS) AS MAAX 
       ,(SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(NUM_PRODS ORDER BY NUM_PRODS SEPARATOR ','),',', 75/100 * COUNT(*) + 1),',', -1) AS DECIMAL) AS 2weeks
         FROM SALES_INFO
         WHERE SALE_DATE >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
         ORDER BY 2weeks limit 1) as 2weeks
FROM 
    SALES_INFO
```

You didn't specify the relations between this two queries nor their data structure, so for now its limited for the first result, if thats not what you need, update your requirement and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Perfect Sagi. Thank you. A slight correction to the answer. The inner select query needs to look as this - `SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(NUM_PRODS ORDER BY NUM_PRODS SEPARATOR ','),',', 75/100 * COUNT(*) + 1),',', -1) AS DECIMAL)  AS 2weeks
         FROM SALES_INFO
         WHERE SALE_DATE >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)ORDER BY 2weeks limit 1)`

Comment: If you can update the answer with this, I'll accept it right away